# How to make authentication on an app with bcrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

I'm making react native app that requires authentication and making backend part on node. 
I read the description about bcryptjs and it's pretty straightforward, but there's something I don't understand. I need to check hashed password with the not hashed one. which means if the operation is done on the server, I need to send plain text password to the server. Which is not really safe. Of course I can pull out hash and compare on the client side, but then how does the server know if it's correct?

Comment: It's not unsafe to send the plaintext password to the server. See e.g. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64631/is-it-safe-to-send-clear-usernames-passwords-on-a-https-connection-to-authentica

Comment: use passport with local strategy to authenticate the entered password with hashed password. Follow this https://blog.cloudboost.io/node-js-authentication-with-passport-4a125f264cd4